# Using XML PATH command in SQL Server to combine multiple values into one cell

Tags: sql-server

I need to combine multiple values in 2 columns to display `enter code    >here`in the same row, rolled up by a common value (i.e. email `enter code >here`address, ID)

I have been able to accomplish this with one column using "FOR XML PATH (''),1,1'')".  However, when I try to use this exact same syntax and command >on another column, it does not combine.  So, I get Column A = single value, >and Column B = B1, B2, B3..

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime  
set @StartDate = Getdate() - 1  
set @EndDate = GetDate()  
SELECT DISTINCT  
pat.email as ADDR,  
pat.fname as INS1,  
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + right(rx.script_no,4)  
FROM cprx rx  
WHERE disp.rx_id = rx.rx_id  
and disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id  
and (rx.refills_left is not NULL AND Not(rx.refills_left between -0.1  
and 0.1))  
and len(rx.script_no) = 7  
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')[RxRight4],  
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + left(disp.disp_drug_name,2)  
FROM cprx_disp disp  
WHERE om.order_id = disp.order_id   
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [DrugLeft2]  
FROM csom om (nolock)  


join cprx_disp disp (nolock) on om.order_id = disp.order_id  
join cprx rx (nolock) on disp.rx_id = rx.rx_id and  (rx.refills_left  
is not NULL AND Not(rx.refills_left between -0.1 and 0.1))  
join cppat pat (nolock) on rx.pat_id = pat.pat_id  
join cppat_ins patins (nolock) on pat.pat_id = patins.pat_id  
WHERE (pat.email <> 'none' and pat.email <> ' ' and pat.email IS NOT  
NULL)  
AND ISNULL(pat.status_cn, 0) IN (0, 1, 2)  
AND ISNULL(pat.pat_status_cn, 1) IN (0, 1)  
and ((dispense_date + (disp_days_supply*.75)) BETWEEN @StartDate and  
@Enddate  
and (rx.refills_left is not NULL AND Not(rx.refills_left between -0.1  
and 0.1))  
AND  rx.store_id in (1)  
AND IsNull(rx.manual_add_yn,0) = 0  
AND rx.script_status_cn = 0  
AND disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id)  
Group by Pat.email, Pat.fname, disp.rx_id,disp.rxdisp_id, om.order_id  
Order by INS1,ADDR
```

I included my joins in case that might be my problem.  So, I need to have >the [RxRight4] values all in one row, rolled up by the INS1 and ADDR >values.  It does this fine for [DrugLeft2], but not for [RxRight4].

So, for instance, I need the result to be something like this:

```
ADDR              INS1        RxRight4               DrugLeft2
Joe@gmailcom      ABC Group   1234, 4321, 3124       AB, BC, CD

But, what I get is this:

ADDR              INS1        RxRight4               DrugLeft2
Joe@gmail.com     ABC Group   1234                   AB, BC, CD
Joe@gmail.com     ABC Group   4321                   AB, BC, CD
Joe@gmail.com     ABC Group   3124                   AB, BC, CD
```

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Answer (score 0):

In your main SELECT expression, you have two STUFF functions with nested SELECT expressions. Tables declared in that STUFFs SELECTs in FROM sections is independent in regard to tables declared in JOINs. When you code "FROM cprx rx" and "FROM cprx_disp disp" in STUFF functions that are different tables in regard to "JOIN cprx rx" and "JOIN cprx_disp disp" declarations.

[DrugLeft2] is correct because have "WHERE om.order_id = disp.order_id", but 
[RxRight4] is not directly connected with om table.

Below is your code, only decomposed for readability:

```
      DECLARE @StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime;
      SET @StartDate = Getdate() - 1;
      SET @EndDate = GetDate();

      SELECT DISTINCT  
          pat.email as ADDR,  
          pat.fname as INS1,  
          STUFF((SELECT ', ' + right(rx.script_no,4)  
                 FROM cprx rx  
                 WHERE disp.rx_id = rx.rx_id  
                   AND disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id  
                   AND (rx.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx.refills_left BETWEEN -0.1 AND 0.1))  
                 AND LEN(rx.script_no) = 7  
                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [RxRight4],  

          STUFF((SELECT ', ' + left(disp.disp_drug_name,2)  
                 FROM cprx_disp disp  
                 WHERE om.order_id = disp.order_id   
                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [DrugLeft2]  
      FROM csom om (nolock)  

      JOIN cprx_disp disp (nolock) on om.order_id = disp.order_id  
      JOIN cprx rx (nolock) on disp.rx_id = rx.rx_id AND (rx.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx.refills_left between -0.1 and 0.1))  
      JOIN cppat pat (nolock) on rx.pat_id = pat.pat_id  
      JOIN cppat_ins patins (nolock) on pat.pat_id = patins.pat_id 

      WHERE (pat.email <> 'none' AND pat.email <> ' ' AND pat.email IS NOT NULL)  
            AND ISNULL(pat.status_cn, 0) IN (0, 1, 2)  
            AND ISNULL(pat.pat_status_cn, 1) IN (0, 1)  
            AND ((dispense_date + (disp_days_supply*.75)) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate 
               AND (rx.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx.refills_left between -0.1 AND 0.1)) 
               AND  rx.store_id in (1)  AND ISNULL(rx.manual_add_yn,0) = 0  AND rx.script_status_cn = 0 AND disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id)  

      GROUP BY Pat.email, Pat.fname, disp.rx_id,disp.rxdisp_id, om.order_id  
      ORDER BY INS1,ADDR
```

Comment: Savo, thank you very much for taking the time to point this out.  Sorry for the delay, I have been ill.  I just tried joining the "rx" table with the "om" table with a common value, but still getting the same results.  I will keep at it, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Please, provide some short example of input data from cprx, cprx_disp, cppat_par and cppat_ins tables.

Comment: Savo, I would love to do that, however they contain some personal identifiable information (PHI) which I am not allowed to share.  But the 2 columns that I am pulling from (cprx.script_no) and (cprx_disp.disp_drug_name) are not PHI.  The script_no field just contains a series of 7-digit numbers as an ID field and the disp_drug_name field is filled with certain alpha characters to identify certain prescribed drugs.

But, I have combined both fields [RxRight4] and [DrugLeft2] into one column so that they are rolled up by the ADDR and INS1 columns.  Will see if that will work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I simulated your data with @table variables, notice that I'm not sure what data you really have but I believe this will be is enough to resolve your query.

First, I separated nested SELECTs in STUFF functions from JOINs in the main SELECT. Now, this nested queries will execute separately in each resulting row. Notice, that tables in main JOINs have new aliases disp2 and rx2.

Second, in nested SELECT in STUFF function for [RxRight4] column, I added "JOIN @cprx_disp disp ON om.order_id = disp.order_id" to connect om table with cprx rx through disp table independently from disp2 table in main SELECT.

Third, I commented some WHERE clauses I not figured which data satisfies it:

```
    -- AND LEN(rx.script_no) = 7
    --AND ((dispense_date + (disp_days_supply*.75)) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate 
    --   AND (rx.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx.refills_left between -0.1 AND 0.1)) 
    --   AND  rx.store_id in (1)  AND ISNULL(rx.manual_add_yn,0) = 0  AND rx.script_status_cn = 0 AND disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id)
```

Sample code now looks as:

```
  DECLARE @cppat TABLE (id int, pat_id int, email varchar(20), fname varchar(20), status_cn int, pat_status_cn int );
  DECLARE @cppat_ins TABLE (id int, pat_id int, status_cn int);
  DECLARE @cprx TABLE (id int,rx_id int, last_rxdisp_id int,pat_id int, script_no varchar(10), refills_left int);
  DECLARE @cprx_disp TABLE (id int, rx_id int, order_id int, rxdisp_id int, disp_drug_name varchar(20));
  DECLARE @csom TABLE (order_id int);



  INSERT INTO @cppat (id, pat_id, email, fname, status_cn, pat_status_cn)
  VALUES 
        (1,1,'Joe.gmail.com','ABC GROUP',1,1);

  INSERT INTO @cppat_ins (id, pat_id, status_cn)
  VALUES 
        (1,1,1);

  INSERT INTO @cprx (id, rx_id, last_rxdisp_id, pat_id, script_no, refills_left)
  VALUES 
         (1,1,1,1,'1234',1)
        ,(1,2,1,1,'4321',1)
        ,(1,3,1,1,'3124',1);

 INSERT INTO @cprx_disp (id, rx_id, order_id, rxdisp_id, disp_drug_name)
  VALUES 
          (1,1,1,1,'AB')
         ,(1,2,1,1,'BC')
         ,(1,3,1,1,'CD');

 INSERT INTO @csom (order_id)
 VALUES
        (1);

  DECLARE @StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime;
  SET @StartDate = GETDATE() - 1;
  SET @EndDate = GETDATE();

  SELECT DISTINCT  
      pat.email as ADDR,  
      pat.fname as INS1,  
      STUFF((SELECT ', ' + right(rx.script_no,4)  
             FROM @cprx rx  
             JOIN @cprx_disp disp ON om.order_id = disp.order_id         
             WHERE disp.rx_id = rx.rx_id  
               AND disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id  
             AND (rx.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx.refills_left BETWEEN -0.1 AND 0.1))  
             --AND LEN(rx.script_no) = 7  
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [RxRight4],  

      STUFF((SELECT ', ' + left(disp.disp_drug_name,2)  
             FROM @cprx_disp disp  
             WHERE om.order_id = disp.order_id   
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [DrugLeft2]  
  FROM @csom om 

  JOIN @cprx_disp disp2 ON om.order_id = disp2.order_id  
  JOIN @cprx rx2 ON disp2.rx_id = rx2.rx_id AND (rx2.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx2.refills_left between -0.1 and 0.1))  
  JOIN @cppat pat ON rx2.pat_id = pat.pat_id  
  JOIN @cppat_ins patins ON pat.pat_id = patins.pat_id 

  WHERE (pat.email <> 'none' AND pat.email <> ' ' AND pat.email IS NOT NULL)  
        AND ISNULL(pat.status_cn, 0) IN (0, 1, 2)  
        AND ISNULL(pat.pat_status_cn, 1) IN (0, 1)  
        --AND ((dispense_date + (disp_days_supply*.75)) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate 
        --   AND (rx.refills_left IS NOT NULL AND NOT(rx.refills_left between -0.1 AND 0.1)) 
        --   AND  rx.store_id in (1)  AND ISNULL(rx.manual_add_yn,0) = 0  AND rx.script_status_cn = 0 AND disp.rxdisp_id = rx.last_rxdisp_id)

  GROUP BY Pat.email, Pat.fname, disp2.rx_id,disp2.rxdisp_id, om.order_id  
  ORDER BY INS1,ADDR
```

and the result of the query is:

```
   ADDR                 INS1                 RxRight4            DrugLeft2
   -------------------- -------------------- ------------------- --------------------
   Joe.gmail.com        ABC GROUP             1234, 4321, 3124   AB, BC, CD
```